# ngx_pagespeed - Gzip static assets

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

I am trying to find the best approach for my nginx box. My goal is, of course, the best possible performance, and the best loading times for my users.

So I was load testing my nginx and - with the help of maxim-dounin from nginx forums - found out that my throughput problems was on the fly gzipping of static assets.

I'll have to pre-gzip everything on the build process, thats very easy - and do on the fly gzip for dynamic content only with comp level @ 1 or 2, that shoud save some cpu and allow me to serve as many users as possible with aws m1.small ec2 instance.

But I also intent to use ngx_pagespeed to optimize these static assets, minify, combine, stuff that ngx_pagespeed does so well. I mean, images I can work around and do jpgoptim and pngoptim on build process, but combining css/js is harder.

I am using these ngx_pagespeed config:

```
pagespeed on;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript,canonicalize_javascript_libraries,collapse_whitespace,convert_meta_tags,dedup_inlined_images,flatten_css_imports,inline_import_to_link,inline_css,inline_javascript,rewrite_javascript,remove_comments,rewrite_css,rewrite_images,convert_gif_to_png,recompress_png,convert_jpeg_to_progressive,strip_image_color_profile,strip_image_meta_data,insert_image_dimensions;
pagespeed JpegRecompressionQuality 80;
pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb            256000; #256mb
pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs   3600000;
pagespeed FileCacheInodeLimit        500000;
pagespeed FileCachePath /run/shm/nginx/pagespeed_cache;
pagespeed Statistics on;
pagespeed StatisticsLogging on;
pagespeed LogDir /var/log/pagespeed;
pagespeed LowercaseHtmlNames on;
```

Any ideias on how ngx_pagespeed works with nginx gzip_static? I mean, as far as my understaing go, ngx_pagespeed is running 'in front' of nginx, as it caches everything it optimizes to tmpfs. If the server got a hit for a already optimized asset it servers from tmpfs, and I looked for gzipped files on the cache folder and could not find any.
First of all, ngx_pagespeed does its own gzipping? It does it on the fly or it cache gzipped version?

How does it go when it receives an already gzipped asset from nginx (gzip_static on)? Does it have to unzip and then gzip again after optimization?

How can I have the best of both worlds - serving pre-compressed static assets and ngx_pagespeed optimizations?

Thanks alot and best regards.

Comment: Why are you using gzip_static? If it is because the CPU cost of gzipping is too high, then ngx_pagespeed will definitely be too expensive for your setup. ngx_pagespeed adds quite a bit more CPU use than gzip.

Comment: Thanks for the help. CPU is a limitation, yes, but also is network throughput of the ec2 machine which is 30.000 KB/s, so I need to balance things. I am using gzip_static in order to get best compression level without the waste of cpu. I know pagespeed adds alot of cpu usage but I really would like to have my assets optimized, combined, minified, and I dont have control over the source code.
My question is - ngx_pagespeed is caching my static optimized assets to tmpfs. Every time the user hits the optimized asset, ngx_pagespeed gzips it? Or it keeps a gzipped asset on the cache?

Comment: From my testing, it should be faster. For instance, when a user hits a asset like [/css/A.print.css.pagespeed.cf.54Itr6v-Y8.css], it is fetched from tmpfs cache and server directly. But the throughput is not that good compared to nginx serving static content. So my question has changed a little bit since I have done some testing and reading about this. What does ngx_pagespeed does when [/css/A.print.css.pagespeed.cf.54Itr6v-Y8.css] gets hit and the asset is in cache? Does it serve it directly? Does it gzip and serve? Does it keep a gzipped version? Do I have control over this?

Comment: We do not cache a gzipped version (although we've talked about this). Instead the uncompressed resources is stored in cache and gzipped on-the-fly.

Comment: sligocki - Thank you. I am in love with ngx_pagespeed, it just works, but the cpu consumption is just too much for my servers. I cannot afford it. I believe the major reason why *_pagespeed consumes so much cpu is because of its gzipping on the fly, right? Because it caches the optimized assets to memory and uses it for as long as possible. Its pretty much serving a static file. Can you share the reasons why you guys decided to not keep gzipped version on cache (just out of curiosity). / I am going to try another solution for the minification process. Best regards.

Comment: Glad you like it ddutra. We will keep this in mind. We haven't supported pre-gzipping because we didn't think that that was the performance bottleneck, but it might be worth rethinking.

Comment: Just FYI and anyone that reads this in the future, I was able to accomplish my objective by putting Varnish in front of Nginx. Varnish caches gziped version of assets and of the pages. ngx_pagespeed DownstreamCachePurge is working as it is supposed to by sending PURGE requests to varnish when the optimization (running on background I guess) is complete. The performance is great now. Best regards.

Comment: Ah, great idea. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my objective by putting Varnish in front of Nginx. Varnish caches gziped version of assets and of the pages. ngx_pagespeed Downstream Cache purge (check nxg_pagespeed docs for more info)  is working as it is supposed to by sending PURGE requests to varnish when the optimization (running on background I guess) is complete. The performance is great now.